# Сan't handle form propper way

Tags: wordpress, post, woocommerce, hook

In my plugin I'm trying to change the order data ($total particullary) depending on clicking duplicated buttons 'Place order' with custom value and name attributes which are in the form> element of the checkout page.
This  have url of checkout page as value of action attribute in the form-checkout.php file.
So I can't understand where is it processed. Where can obtain theese $_POST variables?
Is it real to imlement it via plugin? How? I will insanely happy for every piece of advice. 
Wordpress version - 5.3.2. Woocommerce version - 3.5

```
<?php 
/**
 * Plugin Name: 2buttonsplug
 * Description: Description
 * Plugin URI: http://#
 * Author: Author
 * Author URI: http://#
 */

/*
add_action('admin_post_get_for_price_2','mega_function');
add_action('admin_post_get_for_price_3','mega_function');
function mega_function() {
    global $gj;
    $gj=$_POST['get_for_price_2'];

}
*/
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_order_review', 'second_place_order_button', 5 );
function second_place_order_button() {
    $order_button_text = 'get_for_price_2';

    echo '<button type="submit" class="button alt" name="get_lucky_order" id="place_order" value="' . esc_attr( $order_button_text ) . '" data-value="' . esc_attr( $order_button_text ) . '">' . esc_html( $order_button_text ) . '</button>';
    $order_button_text = 'get_for_price_3';
    echo '<button type="submit" class="button alt" name="get_extra_lucky_order" id="place_order" value="' . esc_attr( $order_button_text ) . '" data-value="' . esc_attr( $order_button_text ) . '">' . esc_html( $order_button_text ) . '</button>';

}

//woocommerce_checkout_create_order

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'change_total_on_checking', 20, 1 );

function change_total_on_checking( $order ) {
    $total = $order->get_total();
    $new_total = $total * 1.12;
    $order->set_total( $new_total );

}


?>
```

And form-checkout.php line 32:

```
<form name="checkout" method="post" class="checkout woocommerce-checkout" action="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_checkout_url() ); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot yet comment.

From my experience the checkout is processed with a Ajax call to the server. Now I don't believe you can change the total the way you're doing it, since the order doesn't get recreated. If you look at the official Storefront theme you can see a loading animation. This means the order is being validated but it was already created so the woocommerce_checkout_create_order won't be called. You could implement a [custom payment gateway](https://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-create-a-simple-woocommerce-payment-gateway/).

Secondly, I don't think you can simply set the order total since it can get recalculated based on order items. Also if setting it you should call $order->save(); To save the details.

I recommend you apply a coupon if you're reducing price the price of the order or a fee if increasing it.

You probably could manipulate the order total at the cart page rather than the checkout page. Add your buttons to the cart page and based on that clicked button apply an action to the order.

Note:
in your code you have to specify global $gj outside the mega_function. Also the name of the button is get_lucky_order and get_extra_lucky_order not get_for_price_2 and get_for_price_3

```
...
global $gj;
$gj=0;
add_action('admin_post_get_for_price_2','mega_function');
add_action('admin_post_get_for_price_3','mega_function');
function mega_function() {
    global $gj;
    $gj=$_POST['get_for_price_2']; // value gets set after the action hook gets called, $gj will not have a new value

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_order_review', 'second_place_order_button', 5 );
function second_place_order_button() {
    $order_button_text = 'get_for_price_2';

    echo '<button type="submit" class="button alt" name="get_lucky_order" id="place_order" value="' . esc_attr( $order_button_text ) . '" data-value="' . esc_attr( $order_button_text ) . '">' . esc_html( $order_button_text ) . '</button>';
    $order_button_text = 'get_for_price_3';
    echo '<button type="submit" class="button alt" name="get_extra_lucky_order" id="place_order" value="' . esc_attr( $order_button_text ) . '" data-value="' . esc_attr( $order_button_text ) . '">' . esc_html( $order_button_text ) . '</button>';

}

//woocommerce_checkout_create_order

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'change_total_on_checking', 20, 1 ); // --> if $gj == 0 this doesn't have a valid callback, change_total_on_checking is never defined
if($gj){ --> this will always be 0 even if global is set, because mega_function is called way after this line of code
function change_total_on_checking( $order ) {
    $total = $order->get_total();
    $new_total = $total * 1.12;
    $order->set_total( $new_total );

}
}
```

if you need the validation skip the mega function.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_order_review', 'second_place_order_button', 5 );
function second_place_order_button() {
    // you know the value don't sanitize it and use esc_html__('get_for_price_2',__YOUR__TEXT_DOMAIN); in case you want translations

echo '<button type="submit" class="button alt" name="get_lucky_order" id="place_order" value="get_for_price_2" data-value="get_for_price_2">' . esc_html__('get_for_price_2', __YOUR__TEXT_DOMAIN ) . '</button>';


    echo '<button type="submit" class="button alt" name="get_extra_lucky_order" id="place_order" value="get_for_price_3" data-value="get_for_price_3">' . esc_html__( 'get_for_price_3', __YOUR__TEXT_DOMAIN ). '</button>';

}

//woocommerce_checkout_create_order
$gj=false;
if(isset($_POST['get_lucky_order'])){ // use the name, not the value
  $gj=$_POST['get_lucky_order'];
} else if(isset($_POST['get_extra_lucky_order'])){
  $gj=$_POST['get_extra_lucky_order'];
}


if($gj){
 add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'change_total_on_checking', 20, 1 );
 function change_total_on_checking( $order ) {
    $total = $order->get_total();
    $new_total = $total * 1.12;
    $order->set_total( $new_total );
    $order->save();
 }
}
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT 1:

You can set debugging to true and see what values are actually posted.

/wp-config.php

```
...
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */
...
```

Now you can use error_log($value);
Look at the /wp-content/debug.log for all the errors and notices

/wp-content/plugings/--your--pluging--/file.php

```
...
 //woocommerce_checkout_create_order

//add the action hook always
 add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'change_total_on_checking', 20, 1 );
// might also want to use woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta instead, since 
// after woocommerce_checkout_create_order the order is saved by woocommerce based on the old instance
// not the new one from you
 function change_total_on_checking( $order ) {
  error_log(print_r($_POST,true)); // go to debug.log after checkout update and see what has been returned in the logs
  if(isset($_POST['get_lucky_order'])){ 
    $total = $order->get_total();
    $new_total = $total * 1.12;
    $order->set_total( $new_total );
    $order->save();
  } else if(isset($_POST['get_extra_lucky_order'])){
    ...
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your attention and so thoughtful approach. I really made a bunch of mistakes. But whats for question. 
That's all fine with hook "woocommerce_checkout_create_order", total changes.
However I can't obtain $_POST for this form at all.